# Bind button in DataTemplate to command in the form's ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

My problem is similar to the one described in this question:
[WPF MVVM Button Control Binding in DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772797/wpf-mvvm-button-control-binding-in-datatemplate)

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MissileSharp.Launcher.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MissileSharp Launcher" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!-- when I put the button here (outside the list), the binding works -->
        <!--<Button Content="test" Command="{Binding Path=FireCommand}" />-->
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CommandSets}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- I need the button here (inside the list), and here the binding does NOT work -->
                    <Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=FireCommand}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It's just a `ListBox`, bound to an `ObservableCollection<string>` named `CommandSets` (which is in the ViewModel).
This binding works (it displays a button for each item in the collection).

Now I want to bind the button to a command (`FireCommand`), which is also in the ViewModel.
Here's the relevant part of the ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand FireCommand { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> CommandSets { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.FireCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(this.FireMissile));
    }

    private void FireMissile(Object obj)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("fire");
    }
}
```

The binding of this button does NOT work.
From what I've understood from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772797/wpf-mvvm-button-control-binding-in-datatemplate) I linked above, the binding doesn't work because:
*(correct me if I'm wrong)*

- The button is inside the `ListBox`, so it only "knows" the binding of the `ListBox` (the `ObservableCollection`, in this case), but not the binding of the main window
- I'm trying to bind to a command in the main ViewModel of the main window (which the button doesn't "know")

The command itself is definitely correct, because when I put the button **outside** the `ListBox` (see the XAML above for an example), the binding works and the command is executed.

**Apparently, I "just" need to tell the button to bind to the main ViewModel of the form.

But I'm not able to figure out the right XAML syntax.**

I tried several approaches that I found after some googling, but none of them worked for me:

```
<Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Window}, Path=DataContext.FireCommand}" />

<Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=FireCommand, Source={StaticResource MainWindow}}" />

<Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=FireCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

**Could someone please:**

1. give me the proper XAML to bind the button inside the `ListBox` to a command in the form's `MainViewModel`?
2. point me to a link where this advanced binding stuff is explained in a way that a WPF/MVVM beginner can understand?
   *I'm feeling like I'm just copying and pasting arcane XAML incantations, and so far I don't have any clue (and can't find any good documentation) how I would figure out by myself in which cases I'd need `RelativeSource` or `StaticResource` or whatever instead of a "normal" binding.*

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It's:

```xml
{Binding DataContext.FireCommand,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}
```

No need to walk up to the root unless you actually change the `DataContext` along the way, but as the `ListBox` seems to bind to a property on the main VM this should be enough.

The only thing i recommend reading is the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx), and the [`Binding` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) documentation (including its properties).

---

Also here is a short explanation on how bindings are constructed: A binding consists of a *source* and a *`Path`* relative to that *source*, by default the *source* is the current `DataContext`. Sources that can be set explicitly are: `Source`, `ElementName` & `RelativeSource`. Setting any of those will override the `DataContext` as *source*.

So if you use a *source* like `RelativeSource` and want to access something in the `DataContext` on that level the `DataContext` needs to appear in the *`Path`*.

Comment: Thank you—four hours of debugging are finally over! By the way, it also works with `{Binding DataContext.FireCommand, ElementName=root}`, assuming you set `x:Name="root"` for your `UserControl`. I consider this slightly more elegant.

Comment: @Informagic: Unless your IDE can update bindings when you rename an element, i would recommend using relative source bindings. Name references can also make it difficult to understand the markup, if you overuse them and bind to elements that are "far away".

Comment: In my scenario, work with `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.FireCommand}` hope this could help somebody.

Comment: @Peter-Yu: That is equivalent in most cases. You just set the `Path` property directly. In my answer the path is passed to the `Binding` constructor, which internally sets the `Path` property. (There are some implementation details that can cause problems when using the constructor though.)

Answer (score 5):

This may be considered unrelated by most, but this search is only 1 of 3 results that you'll find searching for data binding commands to controls inside a data template--as it relates to Xamarin Forms.  So, maybe it'll help someone now-a-days.

Like me you may wonder how to bind commands inside a BindableLayout.  Credit jesulink2514 for answering this at Xamarin Forums, where it's probably overlooked by many because of all the comments.  Here's his solution, but I'm including the link below:

```
<ContenPage x:Name="MainPage">
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
              VerticalOptions="Fill"
              x:Name="ListviewCustomer">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
      <Label Text="{Binding Property}"/>
          <Button Command="{Binding BindingContext.ItemCommand, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}" 
                         CommandParameter="{Binding .}">Click me</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/217355/#Comment_217355

Comment: As an additional resource, the code in this link works in my case: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11029/how-to-bind-command-from-viewmodel-to-external-itemtemplate-of-xamarin-forms-listview

Comment: Definitely Helped me.